# Problem installing JDK and JRE

Tags: java

[image]I have some problem installing JDK and JRE. i am following this website http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html.

I am stuck at step 3 where i need to edit the path environment variable. I am using Windows 7 and i can't see the advanced tab.

Btw, is it neccessary to change the environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows 7 via the Control Panel:

1. Click Start -> Control Panel
2. Click "System and Security", the top left option
3. Click "System", third from the top
4. On the left, find "Advanced system settings" at the bottom of the list
5. Click "Environment Variables..." button near the bottom of the dialog

and now you're to the "In 'System Variables' box" step of the page you linked. Note: You can skip over steps 1-3 by opening the Start menu, right clicking "Computer", and going to "Properties".

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got Windows 7 in front of me at the moment, but I'm sure that by right-clicking on My Computer and selecting Properties that you can access the Advanced System Properties somewhere on that page; and then make the appropriate setting suggested by the link you posted.

I'm sorry if these are unclear or not possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible you don't need to edit the path.  Any IDE worth its salt will let you choose which JDK to use, depending on your target JRE.  It's pretty rare that I need to invoke Java from the command line - when I do it's most often through a .bat file that points to java.exe anyway.

If you really need your path set in Windows 7, left-click on the Windows circle in the bottom left of the screen (is it still refered to as the "start" button?), right-click on Computer, then select Properties from the menu.

On the dialog that appears select the Advanced tab, then click the button labeled "Environment Variables" at the bottom of the screen.  It's there you can edit your path.

If you have a command prompt open you'll need to close it and re-open for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Probably not.  It depends on why you are installing Java.  Are you going to use an IDE or are you going to execute Java code from the command line?